# Scala Eclipse : Local maven repository does not download scala library

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I am using scala eclipse for a scala project. I created a maven a project and added scala Nature to it through Eclispe. But I accidently deleted `.m2/repository/org/scala-lang` directory. Now all my project are given error :
`The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/<name>/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar'`.

If I browse `.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8` directory , I can see following files in it

```
_remote.repositories        
scala-library-2.11.8.pom.sha1
scala-library-2.11.8.pom
```

I do not see any jar it. Can anyone help how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should one more time trigger downloading jars for dependencies.
You didn't write which building tool you're using.
If it's maven please execute(it cleans, builds and updates dependencies):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

If it's sbt please use:

```
sbt update
```